Adding image in div before submit and reading on Controller
I have a problem to read a file base64 on Controller.
My file is a cropped image and I add it in form submit. But, when I ask in the controller the answer is null. The code is reported below:
$("#crop").click(function(){
    canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
        type: 'canvas',
        size: 'viewport',
        });
    $modal.modal('hide');
    previewImage = document.getElementById('name');
    previewImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    previewImage.style.display = 'block';
    var croppedImageUrl=previewImage.src;
    getImagePreview(croppedImageUrl);
    });

    function getImagePreview(croppedImageUrl){
          const img=previewImage;
          var image=img.src;
          var imagediv=document.getElementById('preview');
          var newImg=document.createElement('img');
              newImg.id = 'immagine-creata';
              imagediv.innerHTML='';
              newImg.src=image;
              imagediv.appendChild(newImg);}

So, when I click crop, I can read on console the src="base64 etc etc".
In the controller I found:
 public function update(Request $request,$name) 
    {
        $user = User::where('name', $name)->first(); 
        
        $base64Image = $request->file('immagine-creata');
        
        dd($base64Image);

the answer is null. I don't fix the problem. Anyone can help me? Thanks.
In the view there is the new image and the src, below the screen:

